# Snap to the nearest or previous datetime point value every interval

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am hoping to downsample the dataset with uneven sub-hour intervals to 6-hourly, with fixed time points of 00H, 6H, 12H and 18H. If data at these time points exist, keep. If not, use the observation from the nearest previous datapoint **without data manipulation**, keeping original records.

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.DataFrame({'dt': ['2022-10-29 18:00:00', '2022-10-30 00:00:00',
               '2022-10-30 06:00:00', '2022-10-30 12:00:00',
               '2022-10-30 18:00:00', '2022-10-31 00:00:00',
               '2022-10-31 06:00:00', '2022-10-31 12:00:00',
               '2022-10-31 15:00:00', '2022-10-31 15:30:00',
               '2022-10-31 16:00:00', '2022-10-31 16:30:00',
               '2022-10-31 17:00:00', '2022-10-31 17:30:00',
               '2022-10-31 18:00:00', '2022-10-31 18:30:00',
               '2022-10-31 19:00:00', '2022-10-31 19:30:00',
               '2022-10-31 20:00:00', '2022-10-31 20:30:00',
               '2022-10-31 21:00:00', '2022-10-31 21:30:00',
               '2022-10-31 22:00:00', '2022-10-31 22:30:00',
               '2022-10-31 23:00:00', '2022-10-31 23:30:00',
               '2022-11-01 00:00:00', '2022-11-01 00:30:00',
               '2022-11-01 01:00:00', '2022-11-01 01:30:00',
               '2022-11-01 02:00:00', '2022-11-01 02:30:00',
               '2022-11-01 03:00:00', '2022-11-01 03:30:00',
               '2022-11-01 04:00:00', '2022-11-01 04:30:00',
               '2022-11-01 05:00:00', '2022-11-01 05:30:00',
               '2022-11-01 06:00:00', '2022-11-01 06:30:00',
               '2022-11-01 07:00:00', '2022-11-01 07:30:00',
               '2022-11-01 08:00:00', '2022-11-01 08:30:00',
               '2022-11-01 09:00:00', '2022-11-01 09:30:00',
               '2022-11-01 10:00:00', '2022-11-01 10:30:00',
               '2022-11-01 11:00:00', '2022-11-01 11:30:00'],
               'Value': [ 8786.8,    8789.5
,    8787.7,    8789.2,    8789.4,    8790.3
,    8789.6,    8790.5,    8789.7,    8790.6
,    8790.5,    8790.5,    8790.4,    8790.4
,    8790.3,    8790.2,    8790.1,    8790.0
,    8789.9,    8789.8,    8789.7,    8789.5
,    8789.5,    8789.3,    8789.2,    8789.6
,    8789.8,    8789.8,    8789.7,    8789.6
,    8789.7,    8789.5,    8789.5,    8789.3
,    8789.2,    8789.6,    8789.8,    8789.8
,    8789.7,    8789.6,    8789.7,    8789.6
,    8789.5,    8789.3,    8789.2,    8789.6
,    8789.8,    8789.8,    8789.7,    8789.6]})

data.index = pd.DatetimeIndex(data['dt'])
```

But with `data.resample('6H').last()`, strangely I get one data point at 17:30 instead of 18:00 starting at 2022-10-31:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a potential bug to me, I can reproduce it.

Interestingly, `data.resample('6H').first()` seems to give the expected output.

Alternatively, a workaround could be to [`floor`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.floor.html) to 6H and to [`reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html):

```
data.reindex(data.index.floor('6h').unique())
```

Output:

```
                                      dt   Value
dt                                              
2022-10-29 18:00:00  2022-10-29 18:00:00  8786.8
2022-10-30 00:00:00  2022-10-30 00:00:00  8789.5
2022-10-30 06:00:00  2022-10-30 06:00:00  8787.7
2022-10-30 12:00:00  2022-10-30 12:00:00  8789.2
2022-10-30 18:00:00  2022-10-30 18:00:00  8789.4
2022-10-31 00:00:00  2022-10-31 00:00:00  8790.3
2022-10-31 06:00:00  2022-10-31 06:00:00  8789.6
2022-10-31 12:00:00  2022-10-31 12:00:00  8790.5
2022-10-31 18:00:00  2022-10-31 18:00:00  8790.3   # correct
2022-11-01 00:00:00  2022-11-01 00:00:00  8789.8
2022-11-01 06:00:00  2022-11-01 06:00:00  8789.7
```

Comment: Both methods work great! Thank you. Would the course of action here be that I submit a bug report to Pandas?

Comment: @Jane if it's truly a bug yes, but I might be wrong ;)

Comment: The docs actually stated both `last()` and `first()` are deprecated since version 2.1, I may stick to the `floor()` method

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `bfill` and `ffill`?
They should solve your question if you only need to fill in the nearest value

```
data['value'].bfill()
```

You did not give the expected output so this is my best guess